# What is the difference between Selenium and WebDriver seleniumProtocol in DefaultNode.json?

Tags: json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to set up `Selenium Grid 2` and grabbed a sample `json` config file from [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNode.json). My tests are written in C# using `Selenium WebDriver`. I am trying to figure out the difference between these two protocols and which one I should be using for `WebDriver` test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another file [here](//code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/) only for `WebDriver` . My understanding is `"seleniumProtocol": "Selenium"` provides the mechanism for `Selenium 1` and `"seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"` for `Selenium WebDriver`.

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "platform": "WINDOWS",
          "browserName": "internet explorer",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 5,
    "port": 5555,
    "host": ip,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": ip
  }
}
```

Depending on the protocols commandline arguments changes too. I have another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842774/error-forwarding-the-new-session-selenium-grid-2) related to commandline to start the `nodes`