# Error forwarding the new session: Selenium Grid 2

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I have taken latest `Selenium Server` which is 2.45.0 from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/). Followed the documentation and started the hub with the following command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role hub -hubConfig HubConfigFile.json
```

And, the `JSon` file content is:

```
{
  "host": 10.5.0.21,
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets" : [],
  "prioritizer": null,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "timeout": 300000,
  "browserTimeout": 0,
  "maxSession": 5,
  "jettyMaxThreads":-1
}
```

And, the only `Node` with

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig DefaultNode.json

{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "*firefox",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "Selenium"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "*googlechrome",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "Selenium"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "*iexplore",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "seleniumProtocol": "Selenium"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "maxInstances": 5,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "internet explorer",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 5,
    "port": 5555,
    "host": 10.5.0.161,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": 10.5.0.21
  }
}
```

Up to this everything looks great. See the screenshots of the console after registering [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tch56.png)

And, the problem start when I am trying to kick-off the test with:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
capabilities.SetCapability("browserName", "internet explorer");
capabilities.SetCapability("platform", "XP");
capabilities.SetCapability("version", "8.0");
//capabilities.SetCapability("seleniumProtocol", "WebDriver");

Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://10.5.0.21:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

And, it throws:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities [{browserName=internet explorer, version=8.0, platform=XP}]

See the screenshots [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzSaH.png)   [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo4FQ.png) [screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfHOi.png)

*I must say the documentation on Selenium Grid is very frustrating*. I have spent whole day trying to figure out what's going wrong.

*Am I missing something?*

Comment: shouldn't it be new `URL` instead of `Uri`???? just a guess...

Comment: @VivekSingh no it is `Uri`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good amount of research I was able to solve the issue. The command line parameter was wrong since I am using `WebDriver` I had to replace

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig DefaultNode.json`

with

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role webdriver -nodeConfig DefaultNode.json -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=.\IEDriverServer.exe`

which makes sure I have the driver executable set up in correct directory as well.